# how can I join fields of while loop and if statement

Tags: c

I am using almost the same statements or operations in while loop and if statement separately because of their conditions are opposite ;what can I do to decrease number of same statements from two to one,piece of code that I mentioned is below

can you help me...

```
 while(current1!=*head1)
    {
        int new_carpim=(current2->number)(current1->number);
        int updateResult=new_carpim+current3->number;

        if(updateResult==2)
        {
            carry_happend(*head3,current3);

        }

        else
        {
            current3->number=updateResult;
        }

        current1=drive_temp(*head1,temp1,current1);
        current3=drive_temp(*head3,temp3,current3);


    }

    if(current1==*head1)
    {
        int new_carpim=(current2->number)(current1->number);
        int updateResult=new_carpim+current3->number;

        if(updateResult==2)
        {
            carry_happend(*head3,current3);

        }

        else
        {
            current3->number=updateResult;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't  `if(current1==*head1)` redundant? The `while` loop will only break out if just his condition holds true.

Comment: I am on it multiply two binary numbers so I have to take last digit of first number by (current1==*head1)

Comment: I am traversing my linked list from last to head and head is my last digit that I have to use

Comment: @karabugra05, you can run for() loop for count = number_of_digits_in_binary_number. Since you created the linked list for representing the digits of binary representation of number, hence, you must know number_of_digits_in_binary_number. If last two statements to update current1 and current3 should not be called for last iteration then those two statements can be put under if condition 'if (itr != number_of_digits_in_binary_number-1).

Comment: thank you , @cm161, maybe if I don't achive my aim with whiles and ifs I will try your method,actually I thought about it

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(1) //1 = true = (current1==*head or current1!=*head)
    {
        int new_carpim=(current2->number)(current1->number);
        int updateResult=new_carpim+current3->number;

        if(updateResult==2)
        {
            carry_happend(*head3,current3);

        }

        else
        {
            current3->number=updateResult;
        }

        if(current1==*head1){
               break;
        }

        current1=drive_temp(*head1,temp1,current1);
        current3=drive_temp(*head3,temp3,current3);


    }
```

And more generally:

```
while (condition1 || condition2){  //if condition1 || condition2 == true, make sure to break the loop
     if(condition 1)
            //do something for c1
     else if (condition2)
            // do something for c2
     //do something for either c1 or c2
}
```

Comment: but ,after I traversed my current pointer from last node to head node and did some operations on nodes ,I will move current to last node again so the problem is my condition again will be true

Comment: If your'e in the head now you're breaking out of the while loop as you can see in: `if(current1==*head1){  break; }`. You won't reach the lines written after that in that case.